# Firebase database triggers and Rest API in same project?

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function project that I recently updated all the functions.https.onRequest to run through Express to create a REST API service. The APIs work fine. But when I try and deploy the project, none of the previous Firebase database triggers are deployed anymore (Example: CalculateMyStats trigger worked fine, but was removed from my cloud functions list) . Only the rest function is deployed now. Is it possible to have Rest API's and triggers in the same project?

index.ts

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as http from './http';

import { AddLocationIOBookMarks, DistrubuteNotificationData, NewUserEmail } from './users/usersFuncModules';

import { AutoCheckoutCron } from './locations/locationsFuncModule';
import { CalculateMyStats } from './rating/ratingFuncModule';
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from './config/firebaseConfig';
import { LocationsUserCount } from './pushNotifications/pushFuncModule';

export { AddLocationIOBookMarks, DistrubuteNotificationData, NewUserEmail };

export { AutoCheckoutCron };

export { CalculateMyStats };
export { LocationsUserCount };

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: FIREBASE_CONFIG.project_id,
    clientEmail: FIREBASE_CONFIG.client_email,
    privateKey: FIREBASE_CONFIG.private_key
  }),
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_CONFIG.databaseURL
});

admin.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

exports.rest = functions.https.onRequest(http.endpoint);
```

ratingFuncModule.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as http from '../http';
import * as myStatsModule from './calculateMystats';
import * as ratingModule from './rateUser';

import { fsConst } from '../firestoreConst';

const rateRoute = express.Router();
const cors = require('cors');
const corsOptions = http.corsOptions;


export const CalculateMyStats = functions.firestore.document(`${fsConst.USERRATINGS}/{doc-id}`).onWrite((change, context) => {
  const ratedUser = change.after.data();
  return myStatsModule.roundAllMyStats(ratedUser.userId).catch(error => {
    console.error(new Error(error), `| Method: CalculateMyStats`);
  });
});

rateRoute.get('/rate/updateRating', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  const currentUserId = req.query.currentUserId;
  const toBeRatedUserId = req.query.toBeRatedUserId;
  const rateDocId = req.query.rateDocId;
  const rateFormValues = req.query.rateFormValues;


  ratingModule
    .rateCurrentUser(currentUserId, toBeRatedUserId, rateDocId, rateFormValues)
    .then(data => {
      if (rateDocId !== 'undefined') {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(rateDocId));
      } else {

        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(new Error(error), `| Method: updateUserRating`);
    });
});

// Export all routes for rating related http request
module.exports = rateRoute;
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run lint",
      "npm --prefix $RESOURCE_DIR run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/api/v1/**",
      "function": "rest"
    }],
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
  }
}
```

And when I deploy:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Comment: It's possible to have many different kinds of functions in a single project. Please edit the question to show the complete code that doesn't work the way you expect.  It looks like your database triggers are all in other files that you're not showing here.  Also show how you are deploying the functions, and the output from the CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DougStevenson. I have updated the original question. Hopefully it's a little more clean.

Comment: Also show how you are deploying the functions, and the output from the CLI.

Comment: Thanks  @DougStevenson , I forgot about that. Done.

Comment: @DougStevenson do you see anything here that I can change to make it all work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export all your trigger functions alongside your `exports.rest` in `index.ts` like so:

```
import { CalculateMyStats } from './rating/ratingFuncModule';

exports.rest = functions.https.onRequest(http.endpoint); // your existing export
exports.calculateMyStats = CalculateMyStats // trigger function export
```